# Cannot copy text from tmux integrated terminal in update 1.82.2

Tags: tmux, macos, visual-studio-code

I solved this issue of copying text from tmux window inside Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal [by holding Option key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74275178/copy-text-from-tmux-inside-vscode) but with the latest upgrade to 1.82.2 I am not able to copy the text from tmux window anymore.

I tried changing several settings related to terminal, tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> but nothing worked. Is there any solutions to this?